# Model with nested property submitting meet validate error

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have two models `Employee` and `Department` which have an `many-one` relation.

```
@Entity
public class Employee {
    @NotEmpty
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "department_id")
    private Department department;
}
@Entity
public class Department {
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "department")
    private Set<Employee> employees;
}
```

And the controller for `Employee`:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/employees")
public class EmployeeController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addSubmit(@Valid Employee employee, BindingResult result) {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "employee/add";
        } else {
            employeeService.save(employee);
            return "redirect:/employees/" + employee.getId();
        }
    }
}
```

Add Employee form:

```
<div class="control-group ${status.error ? 'error' : ''}">
    <label class="control-label">Department</label>

    <div class="controls">
        <form:select path="department.id" items="${departments}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="name"/>
        <span class="help-inline">${status.errorMessage}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Once I submit the form, I got error:`HV000030: No validator could be found for type: test.simple.model.Department.`

It seems that spring try to auto create the `employee` object which container a `department` property, and it can not validate the `department`.

However my `Department` have the valid annotation like `NotNull` `NotEmpty` for the properties.

And I can add the `Department` by the form.

What's going on?

Comment: `@NotEmpty` isn't valid for a `Deperatment` object, `@NotNull` is. `@NotEmpty` is only for `String`s, `Collection`s or `Array`s.

Comment: @M.Deinum:Thanks you are absolute right! I ask a stupid question.